# Concatenate matrixes to tensor

Tags: python, numpy

I have two (or sometimes more) matrixes, which I want to combine to a tensor. The matrixes e.g. have the shape (100, 400) and when they are combined, they should have the dimensions (2, 100, 400).

How do I do that? I tried it the same way I created matrixes from vectors, but that didn't work:

```
tensor = numpy.concatenate(list_of_matrixes, axis=0)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would tell us how the tensor is defined given some matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want

```
tensor = np.array(list_of_matrices)
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.array([...])` just loves to combine the inputs into a new array along a new axis.  In fact it takes some effort to prevent that.:)

To use `concatenate` you need to add an axis to your arrays.  `axis=0` means 'join on the current 1st axis', so it would produce a (200,400) array.

```
np.concatentate([arr1[None,...], arr2[None,...], axis=0)
```

would do the the trick, or more generally

```
np.concatenate([arr[None,...] for arr in list_arr], axis=0)
```

If you look at the code for `dstack`, `hstack`, `vstack` you'll see that they do this sort of dimension adjustment before passing the task to `concatenate`.

The `np.array` solution is easy, but the concatenate solution is a good learning opportunity.